# Compare Gene enrichment analysis to gene ontology categories of a given gene

Tags: python, bioinformatics, ontology, biopython

I want to compare the results of a gene enrichment analysis of a list of genes to the gene ontology categories of a given gene.

Currently I am using gprofiler to do the enrichment analysis but I am having trouble comparing the analysis to a gene's categories.

```
import gprofiler

glist= ['HOXA10', 'HOXA5', 'HOXA6', 'HOXA3', 'HOXA4', 'HOXA2', 'MYOM3', 'HOXD8']
gname= 'HOXA7'

#Initialize gprofiler
gp = gprofiler.GProfiler(return_dataframe=True)

gp.profile(query={'query1':gname, 'query2':glist}, combined=True)
```

This does a good job of enrichment analysts but a terrible job of comparing it to the specified gene

Answer (score 0):

This code adds a new function perform_gene_enrichment that performs gene enrichment analysis, saves the results to a CSV file (gene_enrichment_results.csv), and returns the enriched terms and p-values. The CSV file will contain all the columns present in the enrichment_results DataFrame.

Make sure to replace the sample logic in get_gene_ontology_categories with your actual implementation to fetch gene ontology categories.

```
import gprofiler
import pandas as pd

def perform_gene_enrichment(glist, gname):
    # Initialize gprofiler
    gp = gprofiler.GProfiler(return_dataframe=True)

    # Perform gene enrichment analysis for the list of genes
    enrichment_results = gp.profile(query=glist, organism='hsapiens', combined=True)

    # Extract relevant information from the enrichment results
    enriched_terms = enrichment_results['name'].tolist()
    p_values = enrichment_results['p_values'].tolist()

    # Save the enrichment results to a CSV file
    enrichment_results.to_csv('gene_enrichment_results.csv', index=False)

    return enriched_terms, p_values

def get_gene_ontology_categories(gene):
    # Implement your logic to fetch gene ontology categories for the specified gene
    # This function should return a list of gene ontology categories or None if not available
    # For now, let's return a sample list, replace it with your actual implementation
    return ['Category1', 'Category2', 'Category3']

glist = ['HOXA10', 'HOXA5', 'HOXA6', 'HOXA3', 'HOXA4', 'HOXA2', 'MYOM3', 'HOXD8']
gname = 'HOXA7'

# Perform gene enrichment analysis and save results to CSV
enriched_terms, p_values = perform_gene_enrichment(glist, gname)

# Retrieve gene ontology categories for the specified gene
gene_categories = get_gene_ontology_categories(gname)

# Check if gene_categories is not None before creating a set
if gene_categories is not None:
    # Compare enriched terms with gene ontology categories
    common_terms = set(enriched_terms) & set(gene_categories)

    # Print or further analyze the common terms
    print("Enriched terms:", enriched_terms)
    print("Gene ontology categories:", gene_categories)
    print("Common terms:", common_terms)
else:
    print("Gene ontology categories not available for", gname)
```

The perform_gene_enrichment function performs gene enrichment analysis for a list of genes (glist), saves the results to a CSV file, and returns the enriched terms and p-values. The comparison with gene ontology categories is also included in the code.